# Can the conditional operator ( ? : ) in C++ be compile time?

Tags: c++, c++17, conditional-operator, compile-time, compile-time-constant

Can the ternary (conditional) operator be used as an analogous to `constexpr if()`, introduced in C++17?

I would like to add some conditionality to member variables initialization in a template. Would the following expression resolve at compile time or runtime? If so, is there any other operator that resolves at compile time such that template specialisation can be avoided?

```
template<int a>
struct hello {
    constexpr static int n = (a != 0) ? 10 : 20;
}
```

Comment: "*such that template specialisation can be avoided*" Why do you want to avoid it?

Comment: @Acorn In favor of conciseness

Comment: You should probably use `constexpr` instead of `const`, especially if compile-time evaluation is important to you (although in this case it will most likely not make a difference.)

Comment: If you only pass in compile-time constant expressions, any decent compiler should be able to evaluate it at compile time.

Comment: Try preprocessor `#if`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "analogous to `constexpr if()`". `if constexpr` *requires* that the condition is a constant expression. It also has certain privileges in template code to discard the branches not taken.

`?:` does not have that functionality.

However `?:` can appear in constant expressions just fine, and it always could. It doesn't make an expression non-constant.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it absolutely can and in fact it could already be used in C++11 before the introduction of `if constexpr`, and *even before C++11* in constant expressions, such as the one in your question.